# Creating a group of test objects with AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to create a repository of data that I can use for testing purposes for an emerging car production and design company.

Beginning Automapper Question:

In this project, I have 2 classes that share the same properties for the most part.  I don't need the Id, so I am ignoring that.

My existing code looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RaceCar, ProductionCar>()

            .Ignore(d => d.fId)   //ignore the ID

            .ForMember(d=> d.ShowRoomName,

                               o=> o.MapFrom(s => s.FactoryName)   //different property names but same thing really

//combine into my new test car    
var testCarObject = Mapper.Map<RaceCar, ProductionCar>()
```

My main requirements are:
1) I need to create 100 of these test car objects
2) and that for every ProductionCar I use, it needs to have a corresponding RaceCar which are matched up by the name(ShowRoomName & FactoryName)

So is there a way of sticking this in some type of loop or array so that I can create the needed 100?

Also, is there a way to ensure that each new test car has the combined FactoryCar and RaceCar?

Thanks!

Comment: What about all of the other properties, do those values need to match?

Comment: @Oh my, are you *The* Jimmy Bogard? I'm sorry I'm just a little star-struck. Thank you for contributing to my question! Anyway, the other properties do need to match up. Essentially, the RaceCar is a ProductionCar with a few additional properties. Each ProductionCar is associated with a RaceCar. In the database, there is a table for ProductionCars and one for RaceCars.

Comment: Do the RaceCars already exist in the database? Or you need to create new things on both sides of the equation?

Comment: Yes, they do exist.  They both exist in the database and the object model as separate classes.

Comment: I meant the test cars - I could give you some LINQ to create ProductionCars based on RaceCars, but are those RaceCars already existing in the database or not that you want to duplicate to ProductionCars? Or are these test cars just junk data?

Comment: The test cars are just junk data for testing purposes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AutoMapper with AutoFixture:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();

var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
    .Select(i => fixture.Create<RaceCar>())
    .Select(car => new { RaceCar = car, ProductionCar = Mapper.Map<RaceCar, ProductionCar>(car))
    .ToList();

items.Profit()
```